# Using tomcat Realm feature to connect to a mySql db and manage the authentication and authorization in a java REST api

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat

I'm trying to use apache tomcat realm feture as explained here:https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html.

in my mySql there are two tables: roles and users. I also have the right relations between them.

In my java REST API which is a dynamic web project in eclipse i added this lines to web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>rest</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>manager</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
   <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
```

I decided to use JDBCRealm method to support realm with a sql server so i followed some examples and i added this lines to the server.xml file that locates in `mypathtoapache/conf` folder:

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
             driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TradingSstemDB"
         connectionName="realm_access" connectionPassword="realmpass"
              userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="password"
          userRoleTable="users_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />
```

I also copied the mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar to  `mypathtoapache/lib`.

Now, i started my java server and tried to access http://localhost:8080/TradingSystemServer/rest/test which returns just an OK message.
Than the "authatication required" popup shows and ask me to insert username and password. However, even when i put valid credentials it still doesn't work. Instead it keeps prompt me that popup...

What could be wrong? and how can i debug this realm feature?